# using php preg_match to find a single number

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I am trying to find a single ID from a HTML page i am pulling with cURL. The id is in a url query string that finishes like so:

```
start_working&locID=12008'
```

Since that's the only place where that piece of text appears in the html i am guessing thats the pattern we are looking for.

All i need is that locID number.

Like:

`preg_match("start_working&locID=".$what_i_want."'")`

I am really bad with regex and preg match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$match = array;
preg_match('/start_working&locID=([0-9]+)\'/', $yourHtmlToParse, $match);
```

Then you can use `$match[1]` for your result.

Answer (score 1):

[`(\d+)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) is the pattern to get you numbers. You also need [`/` delimiters `/`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in your regex.

You might also want to investigate [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) though, after extracting the full URL.

Comment: parse_str() would not work as i am trying to get this ID froma full page of html

Comment: Mario's sugestion is not incorrect, and it WILL work if you fetch full url!